# Many classes using same css property is there some issue with css performance?

Tags: css

is there some css performance low with it:

i.e:

```
#middle, .div-pai, .div-pai2, .capp, .app_menu ul li, .app_barra, .app_cont, .frm_inputs, .bt_pad, .frmlist > div { position:relative; }
```

many ids, classes using same property like above.

thanks.

Comment: ok thanks, i like to use this method it reduce the css file :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this will not significantly impact performance.

Answer (score 0):

When you apply the same styles to multiple elements without repeating the styles you are reducing the overall size of the CSS file.  A smaller style sheet file will download faster so you gain some performance depending on how often you would have repeated the styles.